# Add Screentip to a shape

Tags: excel

I have a shape that I use as a button that displays a msgbox when clicked.

I have added a screentip to the shape using a hyperlink, but clicking the hyperlink stops the assigned macro code from executing.

An example of the macro code:

```
Sub TestMacro()

    MsgBox "Hi, World!"

End Sub
```

Is there a way to add a screentip to my shape without affecting the code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code you've tried and more of an explanation of what's wrong than "not executed". See "[ask]" as well as how to create a [mcve].

Comment: My code? Really?! OK this is my code.. MsgBox "Hi, World!".. I add the screentip by adding bookmark (Link) to the shape.

Comment: I guess the problem there is to have a screentip the shape needs to have a hyperlink.  To follow a hyperlink you click on it - which overrides the macro assignment.  No idea how to get around that one... just thought of a (not perfect) way....

Comment: I've updated the question to hopefully reflect the problem - feel free to roll-back if it's the wrong assumption.

Comment: it's just perfect.. thank u again.

Answer (score 0):

Your screentip is associated with a hyperlink which will cause a cell to be selected.

You can watch for this selection and run the macro when that happens:

```
Option Explicit

Dim rLastSelection As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        TestMacro  'Call your macro here.
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        rLastSelection.Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Else
        Set rLastSelection = Target
    End If
End Sub
```

The `rLastSelection` is used to remember what cell was selected before the hyperlink was followed.  It then reselects that cell after the code has executed.

Not perfect, and there may be a better way, but it works. :)